# How to pronounce the word that start with "C" in Chinese Mandarin?

Tags: pronunciation

This question is not about the tones. It is about how do you pronounce the word that starts with a "C".

```
脆 Cuì
碎 Suì

猜 Cāi
腮 Sāi
```

Above pair of words sound so familiar but I could hear the difference. I don't know whether I repeat it after correctly or not. I have no teacher to hear me out when I repeat it after. So when I pronounce each word that start with a "C" like following, I pronounce it like it starts with the "Ts".

```
脆 Cuì = Tsuì (my pronunciation)
猜 Cāi = Tsāi (my pronunciation)
藏 Cáng = Tsáng (my pronunciation)
从 Cóng = Tsóng (my pronunciation)
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be correct. As a native Chinese speaker, I'm using my Chinese 'C' to pronounce the 'ts' in English. So I think the other way around should be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah , ts is a good approximation.

Of course ts only really occurs at the end of words in English

Read the following out loud:

Bits way

Bits way

Bits way

( again without the Bi )

ts way

ts way

ts way

cui

:)

Comment: Nice technique! And if I see any word that starts with the `Q` or `Z` such as `去` , `请`,  `走` or `在`. Is it also correct to pronounce those words with the `T` as the prefix such as `去`  = `Tqù`, `请` = `Tqǐng`,  `走` = `Tzǒu` or `在`  = `Tzài`.